# What does this sed expression mean?

Tags: sed

I'm trying to tool around with some scripts I have inherited at work and wanted to see if someone could decipher what this expression is attempting to accomplish:

```
|sed -e 's#\(.\{36\}\)\(.*\)#\1|\2#g' | sed -e 's#\(.\{49\}\)\(.*\)#\1|\2#g'
```

I have tried to reverse engineer this via the reference manuals and google, but have not been successful.

Thanks!

Comment: Might as well squeeze into a single substitution `s/\(.\{36\}\)\(.\{12\}\)/\1|\2|/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is two sed statements. The first inserts a pipe character ('|') after the first 36 characters of the line, the second inserts a pipe character after the first 49 characters (including the pipe it inserted in the first step).

As far as I can tell, these could be written more concisely with the same effect:

```
|sed -e 's#\(.\{36\}\)#\1|#' | sed -e 's#\(.\{49\}\)#\1|#'
```

Answer (score 2):

It means

- insert after the first 36 chars of each line a '|'
- in that ouput insert after the first 49 chars a '|'
- all these insertions are done if the line contains at least 36 chars, respectively 49 chars.
- you can do it shorter so:

  `| sed ' s:^.\{36\}:&|:; s:^.\{49\}:&|: '`